# Change the app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="" in the ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my XML-File I have a `ConstaintLayout`. There I have a `ImageView` with this settings:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/game_square"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_game_quadrat"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/game_right"/>
```

How can I access in the java file on the app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1" to change it to for example 0.

Moritz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After change a little bit the other anwsers I find a solution:

```
ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_constraint);
ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
cs.clone(cl);
cs.setHorizontalBias(R.id.game_right, (float) 0);
cs.applyTo(cl);
```

Moritz

Comment: @Moritz It's pretty much what I told you in my answer. Please accept the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 13):

You can try something like

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(context, R.id.activity_constraint);
float biasedValue = 0f;
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(R.id.game_right, biasedValue);
constraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_constraint));
```

Comment: Yeah I know that but how can I change the app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="" 

view.setlayout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1" dosn't exist

Comment: I can't accept your answer because it dosn't work. But you can edit your answer with my code than i give you the accept

Comment: Your question was _How can I access in the java file on the app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1" to change it to for example 0._ and I posted you an example which works. Maybe it doesn't work for your code exactly but you didn't post any code. People are not here to do your work, but to help you. If my answer was not helpful to you, you don't need to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: You can also change The Vertical Bias with the same procedure but putting it ```ConstraintSet.setVertcialBias```

Answer (score 4):

> Change the app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=“” in the ConstraintLayout

Than Use [**ConstraintSet**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)

> This class allows you to define programmatically a set of `constraints` to be used with `ConstraintLayout`. It lets you create and save constraints, and apply them to an existing `ConstraintLayout`. `ConstraintsSet` can be created in various ways:

**CODE**

```
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.game_right);
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_constraint);
    set.clone(constraintLayout);
    set.setHorizontalBias(view,0);
    set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin I use something like

```
fun ConstraintLayout.setHorizontalBias(
    @IdRes targetViewId: Int,
    bias: Float
) {
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(this)
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(targetViewId, bias)
    constraintSet.applyTo(this)
}
```